# Notepad++ does not print to console from perl script

Tags: notepad++, perl, nppexec

I have following perl script:

```
print "test: ";
my $input = <>;
print "result: ", $input;
```

I made NppExec command in Notepad++:

```
NPP_SAVE
perl "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(FILE_NAME)"
```

When I run this command, it will produce:

```
Process started >>>
hello
test: result: hello
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
```

which is highly inappropriate, because it does not print until gets all input . Any advice?

---

## EDIT:

I have found an answer, eventually. Notepad++ console is not terminal so STDOUT is not in *line buffered mode*. When I prepend script with

```
$| = 1;
```

instruction (which makes notepad++ handle hot), then described problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Run Menu from Notepad++ to run Perl file Directly.
1. Go to Run 
2. Type C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "$(FILE_NAME)" or give path of perl exe file.
3. Press Save
4. Assign Shortcut.
and It is Done.
But Console closes pretty fast with this way so add 
[system("pause");] (Remove [] braces) code in your Perl file at the end line to show "print any key to continue" message in console.
Hope this helps